# Étymologie : « dégoûter » vs « déguster »

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

> [disgust (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=disgust&searchmode=none) [⟸] 1590s, from Middle French *desgoust* "strong dislike, repugnance," literally "distaste" (16c., Modern French ***dégoût***), from *desgouster* "have a distaste for," from des- "opposite of" (see [dis-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dis-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + gouster "taste," from Latin *gustare* "to taste" (see [gusto](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gusto&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> [déguster](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9guster) : Du latin [*degustare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/degusto#Latin) [⟸]
>   From [*de*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Latin) (“down from; concerning”) + [*gustō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gusto#Latin) (“taste”), from [*gustus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gustus#Latin) (“a tasting, sampling”).
>
> [dis-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dis-&allowed_in_frame=0) [...] In classical Latin, dis- paralelled [de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0) and had much the same meaning, but in Late Latin dis- came to be the favored form and this passed into Old French as des-, the form used for new compound words formed in Old French, where it increasingly had a privative sense ("not").
>
> In English, many of these words eventually were altered back to dis-, while in French many have been altered back to de-. The usual confusion prevails.

1. Les préfixes de ces deux verbes sont-ils les mêmes ?
2. L'étymon latin (*gustare*) paraît être le même, mais ces 2 verbes diffèrent en [dérivé](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/229234/50720) : « déguster » ressemble à *gustare* plus que « dégoûter ».
3. Cette différence en dérivé, affecte-t-elle la question 1 ci-dessus ?
4. Qu'explique la différence de changement morphologique concernant  *gustare* dans le point 2 ?

PS: [Cette réponse sur ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132231/50720) motive cette question. J'ai cité Etymonline pour « dégoûter », car je ne peux pas trouver une étymologie écrite en français pour ce mot.

Comment: c'est a priori le même verbe mais pas le même préfixe... ou du moins, pas le même sens du préfixe. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de-#la

Comment: Note qui ne répond à rien : la présence du circonflexe indique qu'à une époque, « dégoûter » s'écrivait probablement « dégouster ». On peut alors sans problème imaginer une racine commune à « déguster » et « dégoûter », ce qui va dans le sens de ton point 2. Le Wiktionnaire renvoie à _degustare_ pour déguster. Pour dégoûter, c'est dégoût, puis goût, de _gŭstus_ issu de _gustare_.

Comment: @Chop +1. Je vous remercie de votre observation utile.

Answer (score 1):

Le CRNTL est votre ami !

[Dégoûter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/d%C3%A9guster)

> Étymol. et Hist. 1. 1379 [éd. 1542] part. passé adj. desgouté « qui a perdu l'appétit, qui manque d'entrain » (Jehan de Brie, Le Bon Berger, p. 152 ds T.-L.), sens isolé; 2. a) 2emoitié du xvies. réfl. « se lasser de, prendre en aversion » (Basselin, Vaux de Vire, XXIX ds Littré); b) 1790 part. prés. adj. « décourageant » (Le Moniteur, t. 3, p. 23); 3. 1538 « inspirer du dégoût » (Est., 187 b ds Rom. Forsch., t. 32, p. 43); 1642 part. prés. adj. (Oudin, Recherches fr. et ital.); 1879 part. prés. subst. (Huysmans, Sœurs Vatard, p. 329). Dér. de goût*; préf. dé-*; dés. -er.

[Déguster](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/d%C3%A9guster)

> Étymol. et Hist. 1802 « savourer » (Lav.); 1916 « subir quelque chose de désagréable » (Mac Orlan, Journal, 8 févr. ds Esn. Poilu). Empr. au lat. class. degustare « déguster ».

C'est assez obscur. Mais il y a peut-être une étymologie commune.

Voir [ici](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exehttp://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1036186125;) par exemple pour l'ancien sens de déguster.